# Windows 7 / 8 / 8.1 Create wireless ad-hoc network automatically after the windows start. Including ICS settings?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I am looking into ways of sharing my internet connection using windows netsh features. As the title says, is it possible to set **everything** needed via batch file(including enabling of ICS) and run it automatically right after the windows starts?

If is it so, **how?** I'd like to do it **without using external programs.**

Surfing the web for a while now and got no answers. Found only the "netsh batch", but everytime had to enable Internet Connection Sharing settings manually.

Thanks in advance.
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put wifi.cmd batch script into Startup of Start Menu (C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup), so it will start automatically.

ICS settings should not change as we don't add any new Network Adapter.

Comment: You are right about ICS. But I need to run the script as admin. Tried to do that in properties->advanced but it didn't help(after the start blinks empty cmd window, but the script won't run, nor ask for privileges). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try this solution? [Make Vista launch UAC restricted programs at startup with Task Scheduler](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/make-vista-launch-uac-restricted-programs-at-startup-with-task-scheduler/)